# getting multiple counts in SQL

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

I want my sql query to return me count of all active and past cases. I tried a query like this,

```
SELECT 
    sum(case when need_By > sysdate and status not in (30,40,50) then 1 else 0 end) AS active,
    sum(case when need_by < sysdate and status not in (30,40,50) then 1 else 0 end) AS past
FROM discrepancy
GROUP BY id;
```

This gives me output as follows:

```
ACTIVE PAST
0      1
1      0
0      0
0      1
0      1
```

What i am expecting is ,

```
ACTIVE PAST
  1      3
```

How should I change the query to get the count of active and past records. Also this query will be executed in hibernate and so want to make sure the createNativeQuery works .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT sum(case when need_By > sysdate and status not in (30,40,50) then 1 else 0 end) AS active,
       sum(case when need_by < sysdate and status not in (30,40,50) then 1 else 0 end) AS past
FROM discrepancy;
```

MySQL also has a convenient short-hand notation so you can count the boolean expressions directly:

```
SELECT SUM(need_By > sysdate and status not in (30,40,50)) AS active,
       SUM(need_by < sysdate and status not in (30,40,50)) AS past
FROM discrepancy;
```

And finally, you can move the `NOT IN` to a `WHERE` clause which could improve performance:

```
SELECT SUM(need_By > sysdate) AS active,
       SUM(need_by < sysdate) AS past
FROM discrepancy
WHERE status NOT IN (30, 40, 50);
```

EDIT:

In Oracle, the last would be:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN need_By > sysdate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS active,
       SUM(CASE WHEN need_by < sysdate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS past
FROM discrepancy
WHERE status NOT IN (30, 40, 50);
```

Comment: thank you. the 1st one works. If i try to execute the 2nd and 3rd version i am getting ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: @JNPW . . . You should tag your questions correctly.  You had MySQL as the tag, and it does not produce ORA errors.

Comment: i didnt see that.MySQl was a mistake and i fgured it out.thankyou.